# Write just one repository for all entities in your model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a project using EF6 and MVC4 ,so i created my model using the EF ,so in my project i have a repository layer for my model ,i have about 34 entities in my model and each entity has a repository like this :

```
public    class ClassRepository
    {
        readonly EducationDBEntities _dbcontext = new EducationDBEntities();
        public void AddNewClass(Class cls)
        {
            _dbcontext.Classes.Add(cls);
        }
        public void RemoveClass(Class cls)
        {
            _dbcontext.Classes.Remove(cls);
        }
        public List<Class> GetClasslist()
        {
            return _dbcontext.Classes.ToList();
        }
        public Class FindClassById(int id)
        {
            return _dbcontext.Classes.Find(id);
        }
        public void Update(Class cls)
        {
            _dbcontext.Entry(cls).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        public void Save()
        {
            _dbcontext.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
}
```

It's so time consume to write this code for all entities .

Is there any way to prevent to write this code for all entities ?

I just want to write one repository  to handle all my entities .

Best regards

Comment: Just add an abstract Generic repository on top, make all your repositories inherit from it, and override just when it's needed.

Comment: So it's like the method that i use!!it 's not different

Comment: May be helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/572761/Generic-repository-pattern-using-EF-with-Dependenc

Comment: It's just that you won't have to rewrite your 6 methods in each "concrete" repository... If they behave the same as the "generic methods"

Comment: You would still have 34 repos, but they would be interiting the generic base repository. No code in the child repositories unless you need something specific for that entity.

Comment: Also this describes your problem well: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle

Comment: So but @rosko ,i have a bit problem ,with this method i have to create a repository class for all my entities ???am i right?

Comment: @EA yes you're right. An "almost empty" repository class. But if you want to be able to override some of your method (let's imagine the update is more complicated than in generic repository), you can do this easily.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus in this link http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle i have to add an interface !!!why?

Comment: @EA Well, you don't really HAVE to, but I would call that a good practice (a very good practice in fact)... You'll have more work at first, less when you'll have to do changes.